# Абстракция и моё понимание

Tags: java

> Абстра́кция в объектно-ориентированном программировании — это
>   использование только тех характеристик объекта, которые с достаточной
>   точностью представляют его в данной системе. Основная идея состоит в
>   том, чтобы представить объект минимальным набором полей и методов и
>   при этом с достаточной точностью для решаемой задачи.

И вот еще информация

> Так работает абстракция из ООП: мы вынесли важные
>    данные и методы в базовый класс, а их различия оставили в их
>   классах.

Работал с абстрактным классом и интерфейсом, но не очень понимаю определение, особенно из википедии:

> использование только тех характеристик объекта, которые с достаточной
>   точностью представляют его в данной системе, что?))

Из вот этого:

> Так работает абстракция из ООП: мы вынесли важные
>    данные и методы в базовый класс, а их различия оставили в их
>   классах.

Я понял то, что мы запихиваем в абстрактным класс "много чего", а каждый класс-наследник "берёт" то что ему нужно, поправьте если не прав.

> Абстракция является основой объектно-ориентированного программирования
>   и позволяет работать с объектами, не вдаваясь в особенности их
>   реализации.

Можно пример, непонятно как позволяет работать с объектами, не вдаваясь в особенности их реализации, заранее благодарю.

Comment: Абстракция содержит общность, реализация - частность. Если у двух классов есть методы/поля, которые одинаковы, то они могут быть вынесены в абстрактный класс, чтобы в классах остались только уникальные методы/поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Абстракции нужны для декомпозиции, то есть для уменьшения сложности.

Выделение абстракций -  стандартный прием, не только в программировании, он присущ любому роду деятельности человека, в котором требуется систематизация информации из-за её обилия.

У абстракций есть уровни и они наследуют друг друга.

Каждый уровень абстракции это модель объекта определенной степени детализации, у этой модели **отсутствуют** **незначительные** для данного уровня детали.

Примеры можно найти на каждом углу, например номенклатура в биологии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый уровень характеризуется определенной группой признаков, уровни связаны иерархически. Все признаки группы-предка наследуются потомком.

Когда мы говорим о **виде**, например `Сat` или `Dog`, нас интересуют свойства **вида** или то что его определяет(генотип) и косвенно фенотип, например. то как животное "говорит" - "Гав" или "Мяу" (специально взял пример из уже приведенных ответов). Но нас не интересуют на этом уровне признаки особи, например клички питомцев (тузик и мурзик), они находятся на другом уровне абстракции.

А когда нас интересует **тип** (хордовые, к которому относятся собаки и кошки) нас не интересуют видовые признаки собак и кошек и мы ничего про них не знаем на данном "уровне абстракции", а клички нас тем более не интересуют.

Answer (score 1):

Тут можно прибегнуть к класическим примерам из книжек по Java. Допустим мы хотим иметь в программе описание (абстракцию) животного. Но не всего разнообразия свойств животного, а лишь достаточную абстракцию для нашей программы. Допустим, нам достаточно знать, что животное может "говорить". Теперь мы описываем нашу абстракцию

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract String talk();
}
```

Вот минимально достаточное описание абстракции животного в нашей программе. Нам достаточно того, что животное издает звук. Теперь мы можем конкретизировать животных

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public String talk() {
        return "Гав!";
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    @Overide
    public String talk() {
        return "Мяу!";
    }
}
```

Мы можем наделить другими свойствами объекты Dog и Cat. И если мы работаем в программе именно с этими классами мы можем оперировать этими свойствами. В случае, если мы работаем с абстракцией Animal, мы лишь знаем про то, что животное может "говорить".

Т.е если мы хотим устроить перекличку всех животных в нашей программе, нам не нужно знать, какие именно животные у нас есть, нам достаточно воспользоваться абстракцией Animal.

```
public class AnimalTalks {
    public void doTalks (List<Animal> allAnimals) {
       for (Animal animal : allAnimals) {
           animal.talk();
       }
    }
}
```

Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда абстракцию лучше обсуждать на конкретных примерах.

Для примера рассмотрим два конкретных типа: *массив* и *односвязный список*. Элементы (для определённости — числа) в массиве расположены в оперативной памяти подряд. Такие операции, как получение элемента по индексу выполняются за константное время O(1), а такие, как вставка — занимают время, пропорциональное длине массива O(N).

Элементы списка размещаются в куче и требуют хранения не только непосредственно чисел, но и ссылок на следующий узел. Вставка в начало списка выполняется за константное время O(1), а получение элемента по индексу — за время O(N).

Для некоторых алгоритмов такие характеристики, как скорость извлечения числа по индексу, являются определяющими. Например, *быстрая сортировка Хоара* на массиве выполняется за время O(N×log N), в то время, как на односвязном списке тот же самый алгоритм будет давать O(N<sup>2</sup>×log N) из-за накладных расходов на извлечение произвольного элемента.

Для других алгоритмов скорость работы на разных структурах будет идентична. Например, если мы хотим посчитать сумму чисел в коллекции, то и для массива и для списка эта операция потребует времени O(N).

К сожалению, если мы не абстрагируемся от деталей реализации, код подсчёта суммы для списка и массива будет разным. Мы бы всё-таки хотели, по возможности, писать код один раз для разных случаев, если это не бьёт по производительности.

В случае массива и списка мы можем абстрагироваться от деталей реализации и использовать паттерн проектирования *Итератор*. Мы скажем, что и *массив* и *список* — представители абстрактного типа *коллекция* или *составной объект* (`Iterable`), который позволяет перебирать свои элементы.

*Массив* и *список* будут реализовывать метод коллекции *подать сюда итератор*, в Java он называется `iterator`. Сам *итератор* также является абстрактным типом, который имеет методы `hasNext`, `next` и `remove`.

В результате мы можем написать универсальный метод вычисления суммы элементов целочисленной коллекции:

```
int sum(Iterable<int> iterable)
{
    int result = 0;
    Iterator<int> iterator = iterable.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
        result += iterator.next();

    return result;
}
```

Этот пример ещё нельзя назвать идеальным, но он демонстрирует преимущества абстрактных типов данных.

Тут важно, что *итератор по массиву* и *итератор по списку* — это разные классы, которые работают каждый по своему, но они имеют общий интерфейс, достаточный для наших задач.