# Абстракция и её понятие

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс

> Ты наверняка помнишь, что такое «абстракция» — мы это уже проходили.
>   Если вдруг подзабыл — не страшно, вспомним: это принцип ООП, согласно
>   которому при проектировании классов и создании объектов необходимо
>   выделять только главные свойства сущности, и отбрасывать
>   второстепенные.

Как понять выделять только главные свойства сущности, и отбрасывать второстепенные? Объясните пожалуйста, а то я пропустил по состоянию здоровья лекцию :(

Comment: Спасибо что отредактировали :)

Comment: Наверное те свойства сущности, которые имеют значение для текущей задачи - отбрасывая все ненужное.

Comment: Допустим, вы пишете программу, которая ведёт базу студентов в группе.  Для целей данной программы имя студента, его оценки и посещаемость занятий - важные свойства и их нужно учесть при написании программы. А вот то, что у студентки Маши третий размер груди и она носит откровенные наряды - второстепенные свойства, и при написании программы их нужно отбросить.

Comment: @Xander ну это смотря для чего база создается, возможно и наоборот

Comment: А вот вы же этот вопрос задавали пару дней назад: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972730/Абстракция-и-моё-понимание/972928

Вам там даже ответили несколько человек.

Comment: да я вот тоже хотел сказать что недавно писал ответ на эту тему Вам https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/974485/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да я помню, просто мне надо разобраться именно с этими предложениями

Comment: @MikeMclaren как раз определение принадлежности свойства уровню абстракции это часто нетривиальная задача, поэтому есть хорошие абстракции и откровенно плохие.

Comment: @MikeMclaren вы задавайте дополнительные вопросы, не стесняйтесь

Comment: @StrangerintheQ выделять только главные свойства сущности, и отбрасывать второстепенные. Не пойму этих слов, это можно на примере расписать или объяснить, а то я читаю, а толку 0, не могу достучаться до мозга :)

Comment: @MikeMclaren вот возьмем сетевой маршрутизатор, он принимает пакеты по сети, но они не интересуют его в полном объеме, маршрутизатору важно понять куда отправить пакет и все, вот внутри маршрутизатора сущность, описывающая пакет будет иметь только те поля, которые нужны для обработки этого пакета, допустим адрес получателя и время жизни.

Comment: Абстрактные классы содержат абстрактные методы, а не свойства. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920

Answer (score 1):

Главные свойства выделять очень просто. Это те свойства, которые нужны для конкретной бизнес-логики (т.е. для конкретного приложения). Вот, к примеру, человеское существо. Это сложнейший объект характеризующийся тысячами параметров начиная от его пола, психологических характеристик, внешности и финансового состояния и заканчивая параметрами состояния здоровья, молекулярным строением тканей и химическим составом крови. Но если для приложения требуется только его имя и пол, то мы не тянем в приложение описание человека из предметной области во всей его полноте и сложности. Человек для нас - это только name и gender. Это и есть абстракция.